# Python Error ''No module found: Rioxarray''

Tags: python

I have installed rioxarray using anaconda command prompt with the following code:

```
conda install -c conda-forge rioxarray
```

However, whenever I import the package it gives me error as: **Module not Found.**
I am installing it by creating a new environment. Please help

Comment: First to double check that you have installed `rioxarray` in  the environment do

`conda activate <your_env>`
then run
`conda list`
and ensure that `rioxarray` appears

Comment: It does appear! and I am still getting the same error

Comment: Nice well atleast you know it's installed. So when you run `import rioxarray` does it say that `rioxarray` is not found - or some other dependency?